# Remove checkbox from rows in ag-grid

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid

In my Angular component I have checkbox selection enabled for all of my rows, but I am actually trying to only have a selection box for rows that can flower, in other words rows that `node.canFlower` property is true.

My checkbox selection is implemented in my component like so:

```
ngOnInit(): {
    ...
    this.gridOptions.rowSelection = 'single';
    this.gridOptions.suppressRowClickSelection = true;
}
```

I understand that checkbox selection can be enabled/disabled via a function `colDef.checkboxSelection` that returns true/false according to the official documentation.  How do I remove checkboxes for rows that `node.canFlower = false`?

Comment: For future reference, here is complete info on [disabling checkbox in ag-grid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64012540/7977581).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not tested, but it should be close:

```
const columnDefs = [
    {
        headerName: 'ID',
        field: 'id',
        checkboxSelection: function(params) {
            return params.node.canFlower;
        },
    },
];
```

Comment: It worked but something odd is happening,  I see that the row that does not flower no longer has the checkbox but when I click on that row within that column I get `TypeError: params.checkboxSelection is not a function...`

Comment: I'm not sure why that's happening. Can you share your column definitions and `gridOptions`? Or make a demo showing the problem.